# How does one write a language?

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler-construction, programming-languages

How does one write a language? I really can't imagine how this would be done. Do you have to write some binary code? I think I'm far from capable of writing a real programming language -- I'm a hobby programmer -- but I just want to understand how it works.
I don't ask for 'a working demo' (because I presume that'd be a demo like ten pages long) but the general steps one has to take, what you have to write and what that what you have to write has to do, what language do you recommend (that I think I'm not capable of it doesn't mean I don't want to try).

**EDIT:**
So is my assumption that one would write some code in an arbitrary language that translates it into an already existent language and compile that to machine code?

PS I accidentally voted to reopen my own question, but I think it's reasonable it's closed, so how can I undo that?

Comment: As in, "how would I create C#?" Binary code only enters into play once you actually have a compiler that can build an executable out of something written in your language. Most languages these days are built using some OTHER language, until the tools reach a state where they can become self hosting, e.g. compile its own compiler.

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials, books, papers, methodologies, etc. Start googling. Lexer, parser, code gen/interpretation are the main steps.

Comment: `using some OTHER language`, wouldn't that be an interpreted language?

Comment: First off you need to broaden your mind. There's nothing magical about any of this. A compiler or interpreter is just a program. A program is just a string, or depending on what you represent, a tree or graph or some other data structure. An executable file is just a string. A program which transforms the first into the last is a compiler.

Comment: @11684: no, e.g. PHP is written in C.

Comment: Ah, so most languages are being translated to another language, and then the result is being compiled to binary? @MarcB

Comment: no, they start out being "hosted" in another language. Some stay there, e.g. PHP is most likely never going to be self-hosting, but some others will eventually outgrow their host and go their own way. You could write a full JVM using nothing but java if you so choose, even though Java itself started out as a C or C++ application. On the other hand, Java, C, PHP, etc... all end up being hosted as x86 or PPC or whatever machine-level instructions, so technically ALL languages aren't self-hosted.

Comment: I really don't understand that. So there is C code executing the PHP code?

Comment: No. C code is not executed. C is not something you can run on a cpu. but a compiler will take that C code and translate it into native assembler CPU instructions for whatever platform you're trying to run it on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17889/discussion-between-11684-and-marc-b) @MarcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by writing a specification and grammar that describe what your language does.

Then, write a parser and compiler that turns your language into a simpler language, such as C or MSIL or Javascript.

Finally, run an existing compiler for that language.

You may want to look into LLVM.

Comment: A parser doesn't compile anything.

Comment: So you mean that you'd create a lexer, that reads it in, then a parser that writes it out in, say, C, and then compile the C code?

Comment: @delnan that's not true, depending on your definition of compile and "parser," it's certainly possible to write whole compilers in yacc or similar tools.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski It is indeed perfectly possible to generate code on the fly in parser actions. But that is not just a parser, it's a parser and a code generator coupled together.

Comment: @delnan that's why I said it depends on your definition of parser, for some people the definition of parser is precisely a yacc style parser, for purists it's not.  Still, a parser is defined by translating your source language into an AST, if the AST is viewed as executable, then you can certainly say that determines some amount of intelligence.  This is a continuum, not a concrete.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Count me under the die hards then, because I see no point in conflating two unrelated concepts just because their implementations can be syntactically intermingled. A parser is defined, in about every definition I've read, by the action of reading a token or character string and figuring out syntactic constructs. This may be coupled with AST generation, with code generation, or whatever, but that doesn't make those things parts of the parser. Also note that a program which just checks *whether* a string conforms to a grammar is also a parser (though not a very useful one).

Comment: @delnan I'm aware of the definition (I teach them in my classes!!), but I argue that in practical terms "parser" (the thing made by yacc) serves a different role than "parser" (the thing you talk about in classes on computability and formal language theory).  Anyway, I definitely agree that in purist terms they differ (and agree with you!), but I think it's important to note to other readers the practical uses of a tool like yacc for compiler writing.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Let's agree to disagree then. I am not just objecting as a purist though; code generation brings its own set of challenges *regardless* of whether we re-define "parser" to include it, and parsing tools (including yacc) don't address help with those problems at all, so to me it seems like saying "implementing XML-RPC protocol includes writing a TCP/IP server" -- possibly reflecting real code bases, but not actually helpful.

Comment: @delnan I don't think you read the part where I said I agreed with you...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17893/discussion-between-delnan-and-kristopher-micinski)